# All superuser tabs crashed in chromium

Tags: support

This has happened twice to me today , all the open tabs of superuser crashed simultaneously on Chromium (11.0.697.0 (77441)) , on refreshing the pages come back.
Does anybody know why this is happening  ?

Comment: No support given to beta browsers

Comment: I understand that , but i have been using the browser release for over a week now and had never had any issues until today

Comment: I don't have the problem and I run the latest version of Chrome

Answer (score 4):

Best guess would be that it's a browser issue. I can't think of anything that would cause *all* of the tabs to crash at the same time other then a browser bug.

Answer (score 2):

We only support officially released browsers as a matter of policy. Otherwise we'd go nuts.

Comment: Firefox 4.0 RC2 = "officially released"?

Comment: @hello what? Firefox 4.0 is offically released per http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/